# TeamCity - Map FilePath for an Artifact Dependency to a System Property

Tags: c#, msbuild, continuous-integration, teamcity

I'm using TeamCity as a CI server and have a scenario with two Build Configurations.  Build Configuration `A` generates artifact `File A`.  Build Configuration `B` has an `Artifact Dependency` on `A` and *builds from the same chain*.

I need to configure a `System Property` (so it will be fed into MSBuild) on `B` that contains the full file path to `File A`.  Is there a parameter reference I can use or other way to get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the artifact rules between `Build B` and `Build A`, you can specify a destination path relative to the build agent working directory to copy `File A` to.  For example:

`RelativePathTo/FileA => RelativePath`

Then you can define a system parameter in `Build B` like

`system.MsBuildProperty = %teamcity.build.checkoutDir%/RelativePath/FileA`

which should give you the full path to the `File A` in `Build B`'s checkout directory.  This will be passed to MSBuild as normal.  If you're after the full file path to `File A` in `Build A`'s checkout directory from `Build B` then that's another story, as they could be running on a different agent.

Hopefully this will give you something workable, let us know how it goes.

Comment: Is there a way to get the name of `File A` from a Team City variable?   The file is appended with a version number after every build (so it's actually `File A 1.2.3.xx`).  It would be nice not to have to duplicate the logic for building out the `File A` filename from Build Configuration A in Build Configuration B.

Comment: Not that I know of... but MSBuild supports wildcards in `Include` attrs.  You could try passing a wildcard value to MSBuild and use something like `<FileA Include='path/to/fileA*.*' />` and consume that by references like `@(FileA)` .. but I've no idea what your MSBuild scripts look like.

Comment: Interesting!  Does that include `csproj` files?  The context is I have a Project file (https://github.com/ppittle/pMixins/blob/master/pMixins.ItemTemplate.Package/pMixins.ItemTemplate.Package.csproj).  On line 122, I have a reference to a static nuget package that is to be embedded in the resulting VS Package (vsix).  I am already building the Nuget package in Build A and want Build B (building ItemTemplate.Pacakge.csproj) to replace line 122 with the reference to the Nuget file that was built by Team City.

Comment: OK, I see what you mean.  Well, seeing as `csproj` files are MSBuild files the wildcard approach is valid; your NuGet pkg is simply nothing more than another Content node with all the others in the ItemGroup. But it depends on how you plan on maintaining the csproj file, as editing it manually may cause issues with VS integration etc. [These examples on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171454.aspx) are roughly what I'm suggesting.